# Laravel css and js gives a page not found, avoid specify index.php

Tags: php, laravel

I recently bought a VPS and I'm trying to deploy there a personal laravel project which runs perfectly in localhost.

What I've done is to tar all the project and decompress it on the VPS (/var/www/). I've installed a LAMP, and create the site configuration (/etc/apache2/sites-available/anuncios.com.conf) and enabled it (creating the link on /etc/apache2/sites-available) like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 137.94.162.235
DocumentRoot "/var/www/anuncios.com/public/index.php"
<Directory "/var/www/anuncios.com/public">
AllowOverride all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It's a laravel 5.1.26, with the tipycal .htaccess under the public dir:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The site works but it's not loading the resources like .js or .css files. Checking the link, for instance:

```
http://137.94.162.235/css/externos/bootstrap.min.css
```

I got a Laravel error: 404 Uups, page not found.

Any help for making it work please?

Ownership is 1000:apache2, and permissions are the same that in my localhost (except public that now is 777 just to be sure).

**Edit**: I followed Huzaib's advise and now it loads everithing, the remaining problem is that now I have to address the site as `137.94.162.235/index.php` otherwise `137.94.162.235` it's not working.

Comment: Did you apply all the file permissions required?

Comment: yep, in fact all the public folder is temporarily with 777 just to be sure

Comment: also , it's not a forbidden error, it's a not found one

Comment: Did you try removing `index.php` from the `DocumentRoot`

Comment: I've just tried it, nothing.

Comment: Did you restart the apache service after removing?

Comment: yes, service apache2 restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `apache` configuration, `DocumentRoot` has to be a directory not a file.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/anuncios.com/public/"
```

Make the advised change and then restart the `apache2 service`.

Comment: Yep,  I was just trying that. Now it loads everithing well... the only issue is that to browse the site I need to specify the index.php: `137.94.162.235/index.php` otherwise `137.94.162.235` it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Solved,

Firstly, I followed Huzaib Shafi answer and changed the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/anuncios.com.conf` changing the DocumentRoot to the public folder (not the index.php).

Finally, to avoid having to specify the index.php I had to enable the apache mod rewrite from the command line:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

That allows apache to follow some instructions from the `public/.htaccess`.